# insufficient access rights on cross-reference id while deploy sharing rules

Tags: ant, sharing-rule

Getting the error while on deploy package with sharing rules.

```
...
<sharingCriteriaRules>
    <fullName>Access_Refund_UK_Supervisor_UK</fullName>
    <accessLevel>Edit</accessLevel>
    <label>Access Refund UK Supervisor UK</label>
    <sharedTo>
        <role>Supervisor_UK</role>
    </sharedTo>
    <criteriaItems>
        <field>Customer_Locale__c</field>
        <operation>equals</operation>
        <value>en_GB</value>
    </criteriaItems>
</sharingCriteriaRules>
...
```

Error referenced to the line with the tag `<sharingCriteriaRules>`

Comment: Please make sure the role and the field exists within the package or already exists in the target system